# Django CBV - How can I check a user's custom attributes to allow access to a view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm having a problem when checking custom attributes of a user to allow access to the view.

Lets suppose I just want to allow access to the users that have activated in their userprofile the self_store option.

When i use function views is very easy i put this in the beginning of the view and works fine

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('auth_login')

if not request.user.userprofile.self_store:
    return do_something_here
```

Well like i said is very easy to use and do different things for different options activated or not in my userprofile

But i cant find the way to do this in class based views, if i want to allow access to the users that have activated the self_store option in the usersprofile how can i do for example in this updateview

```
class ClientUpdateView(UpdateView):

model = Client
template_name = "clients/update.html"
pk_url_kwarg = 'client_id'
fields = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'phone',
    'phone_2',
    'address',
]
```

I can use logginrequired mixin perfect but i want to check like i said custom users properties that i use in the userprofile.

The check that i need to make is something like the PermissionRequired Mixin but for the attributes in the userprofile.

Comment: Have a look at the [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

Comment: Thanks! that works perfect, but i only can do one thing, redirect the user if don't have the permission, but in some views i have to check first if the user is authenticated, if not send it to login page, and if is authenticated check if have the attribute active, if not send it to home and show a message. Do you know some way to do this in CBV? Thanks again!

Comment: You could override the `get_login_url` method and return a different url depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 3):

In a CBV you can access request as a *self.request*. So you can easily check your profile attribute as a `self.request.user.profile.attribute`. There is also a `dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` method in a CBV (see description)

> The view part of the view – the method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and returns a HTTP response. 
>   The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET will be delegated to get(), a POST to post(), and so on.

In my opinion, you can validate your user permissions in a dispatch method. For example you can either validate user by profile attributes:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Return 403 if flag is not set in a user profile. """
    if not request.user.profile.has_flag:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

or by user permissions:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Return 403 if user does not have specific permission. """
    if not request.user.has_perm('client_permission.client_edit'):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to validate not a request user but a client itself you may check client permissions while getting object:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    client = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
    if not client.profile.has_flag:
        # The PermissionDenied exception is raised 
        # when a user does not have permission 
        # to perform the action requested.
        raise PermissionDenied
    return client
```

You can read more about dispatch method here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch

I want also to note that if you have a task to check any permissions using Django Rest Framework you may use permission_classes (See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). All that you should do is to define your own permission class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
class UserHasFlag(BasePermission):
    """Check that user has a flag set in a profile. """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.profile.has_flag
```

Your view will be looking like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class ClientUpdateView(UpdateView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, UserHasFlag)
    model = Client
    template_name = "clients/update.html"
    pk_url_kwarg = 'client_id'
    fields = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'phone_2',
        'address',
    ]
```